# Minimize taxes when transferring investments from one account to another

Tags: taxes, investing, canada

Located in Ontario, Canada

I have three investment accounts with managed by a TD-bank **financial planning** account:

- TFSA (currently maxed out)
- RRSP
- Non-Registered

All three accounts have their funds each in a high fee mutual fund (M.E.R. of around 2.33%), which is the motivation for this question.

I am looking at reducing my costs by using a TD-bank **direct investing** investing account, again a `TFSA`, `RRSP`, and `Non-Registered`.

My ultimate goal is close my financial planning accounts and do the investing myself, however, I want to minimize the tax implications of doing so.

### RRSP and TFSA Plan

1. Perform an **in-kind** transfer to the respective account
2. Sell the high fee mutual funds (in new account)
3. Purchase (low fee) ETFs that correspond with my new financial plan

### Non-Registered Plan

1. Sell the high fee mutual funds (as **in-kind** is not possible)
2. Transfer cash to new account
3. Purchase (low fee) ETFs that correspond with my new financial plan

### The question

Is this the most efficient way, in terms of taxes and fees, to move my investments from different accounts and funds?  What other things do I need to look out for in terms of surprises from my bank / the government?